# Why does my program only work half the time?

Tags: c

I have an assignment to write a program for a natural number where its inverse is divisible by its number of digits. A natural number n ( n > 9) is entered from the keyboard. To find and print the largest natural number less than n that its inverse is divisible by its number of digits. If the entered number is not valid, print a corresponding message (Brojot ne e validen).

I have tried :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   int n,r,s=0,a=0;
    int m;
    scanf("%d",&n);
int t=n;
if(t<10)
{ printf("Brojot ne e validen");}
else {
    for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {


    while (n != 0) {
        r = n % 10;
        s = (s * 10) + r;
        n = n / 10;
        a++;

        if (s % a == 0) {
            m = i;
            break;

        }

    }


    }
    printf("%d\n", m);

}
    return 0;
}
```

And when my inputs is 50, it gives the correct answer which is 49, but when I try numbers like 100 or 17 it prints 98 instead of 89 and 16 instead of 7 respectively. I have been baffled by this for more than an hour now

Comment: I would appreciate your help since I am a beginner at this and do not know how to debug or logical flaws in my program.

Comment: We gave you [lots of advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74468357/why-is-my-program-not-working-it-says-error-floating-point-exception-co) when you asked this question a few hours ago.  Why have you deleted that question and posted the same code a second time?

Answer (score 1):

check your logic.
you can check each value by

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int t,r,s=0,a=0;
int m;
scanf("%d",&t);

if(t<10)
{ printf("Brojot ne e validen");}
else {
for (int i = t - 1; i > 0; i--) {


while (t != 0) {
    r = t % 10;
    printf("%d \n", r);
    s = (s * 10) + r;
    printf("%d \n", s);
    t = t / 10;
    printf("%d \n", t);
    a++;

    if (s % a == 0) {
        m = i;
        break;

    }

    }


  }
  printf("%d\n", m);

  }
   return 0;
  }
```

Comment: I am a beginner in programming and especially in C so I do not have a lot of knowledge, from what I can see it should work but it does not.

Comment: @Kratos1919 That's why you need to learn how to debug your code. You can do that by stepping through the code with a debugger. Or you can add `printf`s to the code as suggested in this answer. Try it, and see what gets printed.

Comment: @user3386109 I have tried printing s and a and both of them have been correct, so I still don't know what is not working properly

Comment: Then try printing `i` and `r` and `s` and `t` and see if they are correct.

Comment: @user3386109    for n=50 printf("%d\n", m);  //49
    printf("%d\n",temp);(temporary for i) //1
    printf("%d\n",s); //5
    printf("%d\n",a); //2
    printf("%d\n",t); //50
    printf("%d\n",n); //0
    printf("%d\n",r);   //5

Comment: @Kratos1919 That's great, but 50 isn't the number that has the bug.